# SLF4J: Bridge vs Migrator JARs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, java.util.logging

SLF4J (1.7.5, but really any modern version) ships with several "over" (migrator) JARs:

- `jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar`
- `log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar`

...as well as a "to" (bridge) JAR:

- `jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar`

According to [their docs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html), a migrator:

> ...ease[s] migration to SLF4J from [JCL/log4j]. This jar file is intended as a drop-in replacement for [JCL/log4j]. It implements the[ir] public API but using SLF4J underneath, hence the name "over" SLF4J.

Whereas, the JUL bridge:

> routes all incoming jul records to the SLF4j API.

1. Do I use `jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar` when I have code that logs using JCL, but I want it to use SLF4J? Or something else?
2. When would I use `jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar`? How is the word "to" here used differently than "over"?
3. Why is there no "over" JAR for JUL? Why are there no "to" JARs for JCL and log4j?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, these jars are intended for situations where your project has dependencies out of your control, and these dependencies make use of `JUL` ([java.util.logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/logging/package-summary.html)), `JCL` ([Jakarta Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/)) or `log4j` and you would like to route all logging operations through the `slf4j-api`. Think of it as dynamically replacing all calls to those legacy logging apis with `slf4j-api` equivalents.

Each one of these 3 jars does the same thing for its respective legacy logging framework. The difference in naming (*over* vs *to*) stems from the way this translation is accomplished.

With the above in mind here are the answers to your questions:

1. If the code is under your control, you might as well replace all `JCL` calls with proper `slf4j-api` calls (same goes for any other legacy framework). If the source code is out of your control or you can't be bothered to replace them, you can include `jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar` in your classpath and **exclude** `commons-logging.jar`. That's because `jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar` contains the same classes (or a subset thereof) of `commons-logging.jar` rewritten to send all logging activity to `slf4j-api`. Hence the *over* name.
2. `jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar` works its magic in a slightly different way - hence the *to* name. `JUL` makes use of *handlers*. A handler is any class that extends `java.util.logging.Handler` and is meant to handle (guess what) logging messages (or *records* in JUL terminology). So in this case, in order to route all `JUL` logging to `slf4j-api` we just need to make sure we register only one such handler - the `SLF4JBridgeHandler` (which happens to be the only class contained in `jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar`). The configuration options to do that can be found [here](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html).
3. The difference between *over* and *to* should now be evident. The *over* jars work by replacing the very same classes of the original jars with ones that route all logging to `slf4j-api`. The `JUL` *to* jar doesn't need to do the same kind of class rewriting due to the way `JUL` operates with handlers (and you only need configure one handler that will route all logging to `slf4j-api`).

For more legacy notes check the excellent slf4j [legacy](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) documentation, and also be sure to check [the big picture](http://www.slf4j.org/images/legacy.png) (also linked to from the main legacy article).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that "over" and "to" express either implementation details or are just an inconsisty. Anyway there is nothing to extend in this answer. The picture says everything.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I use jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar when I have code that logs using
>   JCL, but I want it to use SLF4J? Or something else?

You should use the `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` if you want to migrate your application from using JCL to SLF4J. Both JCL and SLF4J serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, for example Log4J. SLF4J is considered a better solution than JCL as it solves various [classloading issues](http://articles.qos.ch/classloader.html) related to the the JCL discovery mechanism. Note that the 1.1 release of JCL includes several changes that are intended to resolve those classloading issues.
There are several use cases where you would like to replace JCL with SLF4J:

- Solve class loader issues related to commons logging
- You realized that SLF4J is a better logging facade than JCL
- You would like to use [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) which natively implements the SLF4J API

While you can completely replace the use of JCL with SLF4J by replacing the JCL API calls with SLF4J API calls, the JCL over SLF4J implementation will allow you to migrate to SLF4J gradually, especially if some of the libraries your software depends on continue to use JCL (for example the [Spring Framework](http://java.dzone.com/articles/use-slf4j-logging-spring)).

> When would I use jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar? How is the word "to" here
>   used differently than "over"?

You should use the `jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar` if your application is using `java.util.logging` (JUL) as its logging framework and you would like to replace it with SLF4J as a logging facade and have the freedom of choosing between other logging implementations . JUL provides the classes and interfaces of the JavaTM 2 platform's core logging facilities. Contrary to `jcl-over-slf4j`, which reimplement JCL, the `jul-to-slf4j` module does not reimplement the `java.util.logging` because packages under the java.* namespace cannot be replaced. Instead, jul-to-slf4j includes a java.util.logging (jul) handler, namely [SLF4JBridgeHandler](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html), which routes all incoming jul records **to** the SLF4j API. Notice the note SLF4J has about the performance of this solution.

> Why is there no "over" JAR for JUL? Why are there no "to" JARs for JCL
>   and log4j?

As described in previous section, packages under the java.* namespace cannot be replaced and therefore there is no possibility to create a "from" bridging module but rather use a solution which routes JUL API calls **to** SLF4J. For other bridging modules this overhead is simply not necessary.